# How to change react Material-UI ToggleButton Color (for selected)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'd like to change the `selected` `<ToggleButton ... />` color to my theme `primary`, but I'm struggling to make it happen.

Here is my code, which fails to change the color to primary at all:

```
...
import { ToggleButtonGroup, ToggleButton } from '@material-ui/lab'
...
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  selected: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
    color: theme.palette.primary.main,
  },
}))
...
...
<ToggleButtonGroup
        value={toggleIndex}
        exclusive
        size='large'
        color='primary'
        onChange={handleFileToggle}
        classes={{ selected: classes.selected }}
      >
        <ToggleButton value={pdfIndex} color='primary'>
          PDF
        </ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton value={1}>Image</ToggleButton>
      </ToggleButtonGroup>
```

I [read how to pass down classes](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/) but I must not be doing it correctly. Any ideas?

Here is the **ToggleButtonGroup source code:** https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui-lab/src/ToggleButtonGroup/ToggleButtonGroup.js

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69707942/13431819 This will better explain the answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set selected background-color of MUI ToggleButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69707814/set-selected-background-color-of-mui-togglebutton)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ToggleButtonGroup` has no `selected` rule name, see [API docs](https://material-ui.com/api/toggle-button-group/#css). You need to apply your styles to the `ToggleButton` component and also bump the specificity a bit:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  selected: {
    "&&": {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
      color: theme.palette.secondary.main
    }
  }
}));
```

```js
<ToggleButton value={"pdf"} classes={{ selected: classes.selected }}>
  PDF
</ToggleButton>
<ToggleButton value={"image"} classes={{ selected: classes.selected }}>
  Image
</ToggleButton>
```

On a related note, unless you are using the `v5` pre-release, neither `ToggleButtonGroup` nor `ToggleButton` accept a `color` prop.

Comment: Thank you! That `&&` was what I was overlooking (as well as putting the classes in the wrong spot, but I did try in that location).