# Set selected background-color of MUI ToggleButton

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm unable to set the background color when the toggle button is selected.
Right now, the buttons work but don't have any specific color when one is selected. I want to have a default color to the Btn 1 and if the user selects any other button, that button should get the default color.

```
<Grid container direction='column'>
        <ToggleButtonGroup
          value={title}
          exclusive
          size='small'
        >
          <ToggleButton onClick={this.handleOnClick}>
            Btn 1
          </ToggleButton>
          <ToggleButton onClick={this.handleOnClick}>
            Btn 2
          </ToggleButton>
          <ToggleButton onClick={this.handleOnClick}>
            Btn 3
          </ToggleButton>
      </ToggleButtonGroup>

      </Grid>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `&.Mui-selected` selector to change the background color of the selected `ToggleButton`. You can see a list of state classes [here](https://mui.com/customization/how-to-customize/#state-classes):

```
import MuiToggleButton from "@mui/material/ToggleButton";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

const ToggleButton = styled(MuiToggleButton)({
  "&.Mui-selected, &.Mui-selected:hover": {
    color: "white",
    backgroundColor: '#00ff00'
  }
});
```

If you want to provide a selected color prop:

```
const ToggleButton = styled(MuiToggleButton)(({ selectedColor }) => ({
  "&.Mui-selected, &.Mui-selected:hover": {
    color: "white",
    backgroundColor: selectedColor
  }
}));
```

```
<ToggleButton value="left" selectedColor="#00abc0">
  <FormatAlignLeftIcon />
</ToggleButton>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: What is the use of &.Mui-selected and &.Mui-selected:hover? I don't understand the syntax.

Comment: @NehaChaudhary `&` means the current component (`ToggleButton`), `&.Mui-selected` means the `ToggleButton` in selected state (you can see the class names of other states [here](https://mui.com/customization/how-to-customize/#heading-state-classes)). `&.Mui-selected:hover` means the selected `ToggleButton` when hovering, you can change it to different color if you want.

Comment: I'm unable to fix the selected Color in my case. Not sure what is going wrong. Can you please check? https://codesandbox.io/s/69707814-set-selected-color-of-toggle-button-group-mui-forked-kindl?file=/demo.js

Comment: @NehaChaudhary your code doesn't work simply because the button is not selected. You need to specify the value of each button by declaring the value prop: `<ToggleButton value='Day'`. I fixed the codesandbox for you [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/69707814-set-selected-color-of-toggle-button-group-mui-forked-s8vcr?file=/demo.js)

Comment: Hey there's a bug in your code which is noticeable when using a darker outline color for the selected toggle button and when NOT hovering over the selected button the left border is missing, I can't figure out how to fix it, please help